# Delete row if remainder is not 0

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am looking for a script that will delete an entire row, if ['D1'] does not give a remainder of 0, when divided by 0.02. Thanks in advance!

Input:

```
D1     Value
0.01    2
0.02    1
0.03    4
0.04    3
0.05    6
0.06    5
```

Desired Output:

```
D1     Value
0.02    1
0.04    3
0.06    5
```

The code I have tested:

```
for q in range(len(df)):
   if (df.loc[q, 'D1']) % 0.02 != 0:
      df.drop(q)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change logic - select rows if equal by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['D1'] % 0.02 == 0]
print (df)
     D1  Value
1  0.02      1
3  0.04      3
```

With drop it is possible, but overcomplicated:

```
df = df.drop(df.index[df['D1'] % 0.02 != 0])
```

EDIT For some reason `0.06 % 0.02=0.019999999999999997` (I think float precision), so  you can multiple values by `100` and compare by `2`:

```
df = df[df['D1'].mul(100) % 2 == 0]
print (df)
     D1  Value
1  0.02      1
3  0.04      3
5  0.06      5
```